# Font too small in Opera

Tags: font-size

Before digging into my css code and showing all font sizes (which will take ages), I'll try to ask a general question: any idea why in Opera the font is very tiny? Chrome, Firefox, IE work fine.

Comment: did you make sure you aren't zoomed out?  Something like a command-0 should set your zoom back to normal

Comment: It's not the issue - images for example display just as they do in other browsers, which combined with the tiny font makes the site look very unproportional.

Plus, SOME text sections look ok - but most of it is a disaster.